# Cake PHP while loop to dispatch events

Tags: php, events, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm working on a legacy Cake PHP 2 project that has a form that once I submit dispatches an event in my project. It works when I click my button, but when I put it into a `while` loop to try and bulk generate 10 events I only ever get 1 generated.

What am I missing?

```php
/**
* Store a new diagnostic action
*/
public function store()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $action = $this->request->data['action'];

        // test event action
        if ($action == 'perform-test-event-dispatch') {

            $count = 0;
            while ($count < 10) {
                CakeEventManager::instance()->dispatch(new CakeEvent(
                    'QueueManagerModule.QueueManagerJob.dispatchJob', $this, array(
                        'job' => 'TypicodeApi',
                        'arguments' => [
                            'endpoint' => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                            'timeout' => 30
                        ]
                    )
                ));
                $count++;
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash("$action signal successfully requested.");
        }

        return $this->redirect('/queue/settings');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no error during dispatching?

Comment: Nope, no error at all is being logged to my `error.log`, and it is indeed dispatching an entry, I've even tried adding a `sleep(2)` in my while loop and even tried a regular `for` loop, how strange...

Comment: Try sending event with argument that will contain loop number. maybe cake is removing doubled events

Comment: Turns out it was to do with having to call `create()` before a model `save()`, thanks for the help.